# Need help creating Creating Controller to Delete item from database

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

Good evening everyone! I have been following along with a tutorial to learn how to program in .NET. The tutorial goes over how to add an item but it doesn't cover deletion. Here is my code:

Service Layer

```
    public async Task Delete(int locationId)
    {
        var location = _context.Locations.Where(l => l.Id == locationId);
        _context.Remove(location);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Controller

```
    public IActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        _locationService.Delete(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Location");
    }
```

View

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="locationIndexTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Delete Location</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var location in Model.LocationList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a asp-controller="Location" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@location.Id">
                    @location.Name
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @location.Address
            </td>
            <td>
                @location.PhoneNumber
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-controller="Location" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@location.Id" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">TODO Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

My button clicks through and redirects back to my location index view. However it does not delete the location from the database as intended. I know the issue must lie with the controller.

In the off chance that this will help someone in the future here is what I changed my code to to get it to work:
Service Layer

```
        public async Task Delete(int locationId)
    {
        var location = _context.Locations.SingleOrDefault(l => l.Id == locationId);
        _context.Remove(location);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Controller

```
public async Task <IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        await _locationService.Delete(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Location");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the `where` method! It returns a collection and EF's `Remove` method does not complain about it as it takes an object. Try changing that with `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` or the `Find` method and you will be good to go.

```
public async Task Delete(int locationId)
{
    var location = _context.Locations.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == locationId);
    _context.Remove(location);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

However if you tried using the `Generic` version, you would surely notice the problem immediately. A better way would be to to:

```
//EF Core 
var item = await dbContext.FindAsync<Location>(locationId);
dbContext.Remove<Location>(item);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I made your recommended changes, however, it is still not removing thew item and I am not getting an error just the redirect as is expected after the delete.

Comment: I just figured out how to get my code working and I tried it without your code and then combined my update with yours and it is now deleting as intended! I'm going to paste my solution up top because I don't know how to comment on here with formatting

Comment: @Transcendent I'm curious, why is the generic version better? Because the Remove method takes an explicit type?

Comment: @CoreyBryant: The reason why ,y recommended solution might not have worked for you is because, the id of the location MUST be the primary key. So I guess in your case, it is not the PK.

Comment: @ArnovanBoven: In short, when you know what type you are dealing with, generics work faster than casting an object or determining its type in C#. In Java, it is another story because generics are treated as objects all the time.